# What is status of OpenSceneGraph (OSG) plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Does anyone know if the OSG plugin for QGIS is working?
If so does anyone knows what the future plans is for OSG plugin in QGIS?
I am using QGIS version 1.8.0-Lisboa.

I keep getting the following errors when selecting the "launch Globe" menu option, with the WorldWind elevation type. `UnsupportedOperationException: GeometryGraph::add(Geometry &): unknown geometry type: N4geos4geom7PolygonE`

Comment: Vote for closed, too localized. In two months no one has responded, though there is interest in the question. Theuns, I think you'd be better served by asking this particular question on the Qgis mailing list or forums (or wherever the home base for the OSG plugin is).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is at the [QGIS issue tracker](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4053). Still no resolution as of now I'm afraid.